# Finding a Field in an parsed HTML content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to get the table from https://www.innovatoretfs.com/etf/default.aspx?ticker=kjul
I just want the top-right table [image]

I wrote the  code in python and was able to get till the parsed HTML content and got the contents.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.innovatoretfs.com/etf/default.aspx?ticker=kjul"
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
table_it=soup.find_all(class_="al_fund")
value_it=soup.find_all(class_="ar_fund")
print(table_it)
print(value_it)
```

But I am not able to get the final values in a table coz of the HTML formal. can some one please help?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to grab all the values for given divs and then `zip` them all together.

Here's how:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def extractor(s: BeautifulSoup, tag: str, cls: str) -> list:
    return [i.getText() for i in s.find_all(tag, class_=cls)]


url = "https://www.innovatoretfs.com/etf/default.aspx?ticker=kjul"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

row_names = extractor(soup, "div", "al_fund")
row_values = extractor(soup, "div", "ar_fund")

for k, v in list(zip(row_names, row_values))[:6]:
    print(f"{k}\t{v}")
```

Output:

```
Ticker  KJUL
Listing Date    7/1/2020
Number of Holdings  7
Expense Ratio   0.79%
Intraday NAV    KJUL.IV
Exchange    Cboe BZX
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy way to get the desired content is like the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.innovatoretfs.com/etf/default.aspx?ticker=kjul'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".noshadecol")[:6]:
        title = item.select_one(".al_fund").text
        value = item.select_one(".ar_fund").text
        print(title,value)
```

Output:

```
Ticker KJUL
Listing Date 7/1/2020
Number of Holdings 7
Expense Ratio 0.79%
Intraday NAV KJUL.IV
Exchange Cboe BZX
```

Answer (score 1):

with respect to the structure of HTML you did right to extract `al_fund` and `ar_fund`. You just need to add this code to print the table :

```
for i in range(6):
    print(f'{table_it[i].text} : {value_it[i].text}')

Ticker : KJUL
Listing Date : 7/1/2020
Number of Holdings : 7
Expense Ratio : 0.79%
Intraday NAV : KJUL.IV
Exchange : Cboe BZX
```